# Why pool of processes?

Tags: meaning, etymology, meaning-in-context, programming

I hit the [sentence](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3148/):

> The *ProcessPoolExecutor* class is an *Executor* subclass that uses a pool
>   of processes to execute calls asynchronously.

I was looking for the word [pool](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/pool_1) which means `swimming pool` in most cases. So, I'm asking the question: Why we're using in concurrent programming terminology the term `pool of processes` and not `list of processes`, `set of processes` etc. How did the term come into existence? Where is the origin?

Comment: You might want to ask this over on http://stackoverflow.com/ Quick answer: a pool is a group of resources that a program allocates and which is shared by functions/instances/processes/threads/etc.

Comment: @JeffSahol I'm aware of stackoverflow, but believe here are more programmers interested in language. Tao and Lynn defined it even more precise.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would imagine that it means a collection here. This from OALD - *a supply of things or money that is shared by a group of people and can be used when needed*

For example:

*A car pool*

*Let's pool our resources.*

*We have a pool of free-lancers we can call in if necessary.*

Comment: So, why we don't rather use `collection of processes` or `bunch of processes` or `group of processes`?

Comment: It may merely be convention now, but "pool" also implies the *sum total* of communal resources. For example, a *betting pool* is the combined stakes of all participating gamblers, not just any group of gamblers; a company's *typing pool* (in the days before widespread personal computing) would be all members of a team solely dedicated to typing.

Comment: @xralf: The main distinction is that a pool (in the sense of a collection - connections, processes, etc) implies sharing; none of `collection`, `bunch` or `group` have that implication.

Comment: @RandomIdeaEnglish I realized that your answer is perfectly right, but I understood it after reading the answers of others. Your answer is nice short and good summary.

Answer (score 5):

RandomIdeaEnglish has the right idea.  The origin is from [this definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pool) of pool:

> any communal combination of resources, funds, etc: a typing pool

While you're correct that collection/bunch/group would make sense in reference to *processes*, the term dates back much earlier in reference to other types of shared resources.  I believe memory was the first, though I can't find confirmation of that, only this citation from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699057/why-are-two-different-concepts-both-called-heap):

> The term heap (meaning memory pool) was used at least as early as 1971 by Wijngaarden in discussions of Algol.

It would not make sense to refer to a "bunch" of memory, or a "group" of memory.   Nor would it make much sense to refer to a "heap" of processes.   Whereas "pool" works equally well for a wide variety of resource types.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Pool of memory = shared memory regions and pool of processes = bunch of processes that share processor time and the pool is changing while processes execute. As Tao comments there is implication of sharing.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Online Etymology Dictionary, the use of **pool** in the sense of "*[common reservoir of resources](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pool&allowed_in_frame=0)*" dates from 1917.

Other terms like *list* or *set* don't embody the sense of a **common reservoir**, which is explicit in this definition of **pool**.

Comment: Thank you for finding the root of the word. I think that in case of `pool of processes`, the common reservoir is `time of the processor shared by processes`. So `pool` means a group of entities that share some resource.

Comment: Actually, the _shared resource_ is the pool. Read this excellent article explaining a [connection pool](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/C/connection_pool.html); the concepts are the same for all pools used in computing.